# Replace diagonal elements with vector in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, diagonal

I have been searching everywhere for something equivalent of the following to PyTorch, but I cannot find anything.

```
L_1 = np.tril(np.random.normal(scale=1., size=(D, D)), k=0)
L_1[np.diag_indices_from(L_1)] = np.exp(np.diagonal(L_1))
```

I guess there is no way to replace the diagonal elements in such an elegant way using Pytorch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that such a functionality is implemented as of now. But, you can implement the same functionality using `mask` as follows.

```
# Assuming v to be the vector and a be the tensor whose diagonal is to be replaced
mask = torch.diag(torch.ones_like(v))
out = mask*torch.diag(v) + (1. - mask)*a
```

So, your implementation will be something like

```
L_1 = torch.tril(torch.randn((D, D)))
v = torch.exp(torch.diag(L_1))
mask = torch.diag(torch.ones_like(v))
L_1 = mask*torch.diag(v) + (1. - mask)*L_1
```

Not as elegant as numpy, but not too bad either.

Comment: Indeed, I was expecting something more elegant, but this also works.

Comment: Will this solution keep the grad requirement if both the tensor and vector require grad?

Comment: Yeah. I guess so, because all the functions being used are differentiable in PyTorch. You can use this and see if any error pops up.

Comment: can you explain the code as well?

Answer (score 4):

**There is an easier way to do it**

```
dest_matrix[range(len(dest_matrix)), range(len(dest_matrix))] = source_vector
```

In fact we have to generate diagonal indices ourselves.

**Usage example:**

```
dest_matrix = torch.randint(10, (3, 3))
source_vector = torch.randint(100, 200, (len(dest_matrix), ))
print('dest_matrix:\n', dest_matrix)
print('source_vector:\n', source_vector)

dest_matrix[range(len(dest_matrix)), range(len(dest_matrix))] = source_vector

print('result:\n', dest_matrix)

# dest_matrix:
#  tensor([[3, 2, 5],
#         [0, 3, 5],
#         [3, 1, 1]])
# source_vector:
#  tensor([182, 169, 147])
# result:
#  tensor([[182,   2,   5],
#         [  0, 169,   5],
#         [  3,   1, 147]])
```

in case `dest_matrix` is not square you have to take `min(dest_matrix.size())` instead of `len(dest_matrix)` in `range()`

Not as elegant as `numpy` but this doesn't require to store a new matrix of indices.

And yes, **this preserves gradients**

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the diagonal elements with `diagonal()`, and then assign the transformed values inplace with [`copy_()`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/replace-diagonal-elements-with-vector/15311/49?u=iacob):

```py
new_diags = L_1.diagonal().exp()
L_1.diagonal().copy_(new_diags)
```

Comment: Simpler constant case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512313/masking-diagonal-to-a-specific-value-with-torch-tensors/66760701#66760701

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's say you have a matrix `L_1` and want to replace it's diagonal with zeros. You can do this in multiple ways.

Using `fill_diagonal_()`:

```
L_1 = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=torch.float32)
L_1 = L_1.fill_diagonal_(0.)
```

Using advanced indexing:

```
L_1 = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=torch.float32)
length = len(L_1)
zero_vector = torch.zeros(length, dtype=torch.float32)
L_1[range(length), range(length)] = zero_vector
```

Using `scatter_()`:

```
L_1 = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=torch.float32)  
diag_idx = torch.arange(len(L_1)).unsqueeze(1)
zero_matrix = torch.zeros(L_1.shape, dtype=torch.float32)
L_1 = L_1.scatter_(1, diag_idx, zero_matrix)
```

Note that all of the above solutions are in-place operations and will affect the backward pass, because the original value might be needed to compute it. So if you want to keep the backward pass unaffected, meaning to "break the graph" by not recording the change (operation), meaning not computing the gradients in the backward pass corresponding to what you computed in the forward pass, then you can just add the `.data` when using advanced indexing or `scatter_()`.

Using advanced indexing with `.data`:

```
L_1 = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=torch.float32)
length = len(L_1)
zero_vector = torch.zeros(length, dtype=torch.float32)
L_1[range(length), range(length)] = zero_vector.data
```

Using `scatter_()` with `.data`:

```
L_1 = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=torch.float32)  
diag_idx = torch.arange(len(L_1)).unsqueeze(1)
zero_matrix = torch.zeros(L_1.shape, dtype=torch.float32)
L_1 = L_1.scatter_(1, diag_idx, zero_matrix.data)
```

For reference check out [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/replace-diagonal-elements-with-vector/15311) discussion.