# Masking diagonal to a specific value with PyTorch tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, diagonal

How do I fill the diagonal with a value in torch? In numpy you can do:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 3), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 5)

array([[5, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 5]])
```

I know that `torch.diag()` returns the diagonal, but how to use this as a mask to assign new values is beyond me. I haven't been able to find the answer here or in the PyTorch documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in PyTorch using [`fill_diagonal_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.fill_diagonal_):

```py
>>> a = torch.zeros(3, 3)
>>> a.fill_diagonal_(5)
tensor([[5, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 0],
        [0, 0, 5]])
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it:

```
>>> import torch
>>> n = 3
>>> t = torch.zeros((n,n))
>>> t[torch.eye(n).byte()] = 5
>>> t

 5  0  0
 0  5  0
 0  0  5
[torch.FloatTensor of size 3x3]
```

Comment: In higher version of pytorch, you'd better transfer to use torch.eye(n).bool().