# Zero diagonal of a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, diagonal

Is there a **simple** way to zero the diagonal of a PyTorch tensor?

For example I have:

```
tensor([[2.7183, 0.4005, 2.7183, 0.5236],
        [0.4005, 2.7183, 0.4004, 1.3469],
        [2.7183, 0.4004, 2.7183, 0.5239],
        [0.5236, 1.3469, 0.5239, 2.7183]])
```

And I want to get:

```
tensor([[0.0000, 0.4005, 2.7183, 0.5236],
        [0.4005, 0.0000, 0.4004, 1.3469],
        [2.7183, 0.4004, 0.0000, 0.5239],
        [0.5236, 1.3469, 0.5239, 0.0000]])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512313/masking-diagonal-to-a-specific-value-with-pytorch-tensors/66760701#66760701

Answer (score 5):

I believe the simplest would be to use [`torch.diagonal`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.diagonal.html):

```
z = torch.randn(4,4)
torch.diagonal(z, 0).zero_()
print(z)
>>> tensor([[ 0.0000, -0.6211,  0.1120,  0.8362],
            [-0.1043,  0.0000,  0.1770,  0.4197],
            [ 0.7211,  0.1138,  0.0000, -0.7486], 
            [-0.5434, -0.8265, -0.2436,  0.0000]])
```

This way, the code is perfectly explicit, and you delegate the performance to pytorch's built in functions.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use:

```py
x.fill_diagonal_(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a couple ways to do that, simplest one would be to go directly:

```
import torch

tensor = torch.rand(4, 4)
tensor[torch.arange(tensor.shape[0]), torch.arange(tensor.shape[1])] = 0
```

This one broadcasts `0` value across all pairs, e.g. `(0, 0), (1, 1), ..., (n, n)`

Another way would be (readability is debatable) to use the inverse of `torch.eye` like this:

```
tensor = torch.rand(4, 4)
tensor *= ~(torch.eye(*tensor.shape).bool())
```

This one creates additional matrix and does way more operations, hence I'd stick with the first version.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to indexing with two tensors separately, you could achieve this using a combination of [`torch.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat.html), and [`torch.split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html), taking advantage of the fact the latter returns a *tuple*:

```
>>> x[torch.arange(len(x)).repeat(2).split(len(x))] = 0
>>> x
tensor([[0.0000, 0.4005, 2.7183, 0.5236],
        [0.4005, 0.0000, 0.4004, 1.3469],
        [2.7183, 0.4004, 0.0000, 0.5239],
        [0.5236, 1.3469, 0.5239, 0.0000]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```py
x.flatten()[::(x.shape[-1]+1)] = 0
```