# Zeroing the diagonal of a matrix by multiplying by (1-I)

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

I have a tensor, lets say like this:

```
tensor([[2.7183, 0.4005, 2.7183, 0.5236],
    [0.4005, 2.7183, 0.4004, 1.3469],
    [2.7183, 0.4004, 2.7183, 0.5239],
    [0.5236, 1.3469, 0.5239, 2.7183]])
```

And I want to zero its main diagonal by multiplying it by (1-I), meaning by 1 minus the
identity matrix.
How can I do this in pytorch?

Result of the example should be:

```
    tensor([[0.0000, 0.4005, 2.7183, 0.5236],
    [0.4005, 0.0000, 0.4004, 1.3469],
    [2.7183, 0.4004, 0.0000, 0.5239],
    [0.5236, 1.3469, 0.5239, 0.0000]])
```

I'm looking for a general case solution and not specific to the example I gave.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero diagonal of a PyTorch tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712349/zero-diagonal-of-a-pytorch-tensor)

Answer (score 1):

`torch.eye` will be helpful for generating identity matrix

```
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[2.7183, 0.4005, 2.7183, 0.5236],
    [0.4005, 2.7183, 0.4004, 1.3469],
    [2.7183, 0.4004, 2.7183, 0.5239],
    [0.5236, 1.3469, 0.5239, 2.7183]],dtype=torch.float32)
y = 1-torch.eye(x.size()[0],dtype=torch.float32)  #only if x is square matrix
output = x*y
```

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch has a [built in function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66761556/9067615) to do this inplace:

```py
x.fill_diagonal_(0)
```

You can either apply this to your matrix directly, or if you really want `1 - I` can apply it to a ones matrix:

```py
1 - torch.eye(n)

# Alternatively
torch.ones(n,n).fill_diagonal_(0)
```