# About pytorch tensor caculation

Tags: matrix, pytorch

I want to ask a question about torch calculation that if I only want to subtract the elements on the diagonal of the matrix without changing the elements in the remaining positions, is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by getting the diagonal, doint the required operation on its elements and replacing the original one. Example code:

```
x = torch.rand(3, 3)
#get the original diagonal and for example substract 3
replaced_diag = x.diagonal() - 3
#replace the original diagonal
x.diagonal().copy_(replaced_diag)
```

For reference look at this: [Replace diagonal elements with vector in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429147/replace-diagonal-elements-with-vector-in-pytorch)